# combine two arrows

Tags: macros, arrows

I want to combine arrows to obtain like this arrows

[image]

I did manage to create this [image] with this code, but it didnt work for the rest .

```
\newcommand*{\twoheadleftrightarrow}{%
    \twoheadleftarrow
    \mathrel{\mkern-15mu}%
    \twoheadrightarrow
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to have this arrows?

Comment: if drawing of this arrows is an option, see the `arrows.meta` TikZ library (page 198m TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/) is a good place to look in such cases (it has a whole Chapter on arrows!). From the list, the `stix` package supplies all arrows you requested at once (see Tables 159–160 of the linked manual)

**Result**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$   \begin{array}{l}
    f \in S \nvrightarrowtail T\\
    f \in S \rightarrowtail T \\
    f \in S \nvtwoheadrightarrow T\\
    f \in S \twoheadrightarrow T\\
    f \in S \twoheadrightarrowtail T
    \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's good,  but it doesn't work for me, when i use the stix package in my document i dont get the output pdf , even when i use you example the same thing happened no output file :s :s

Comment: @Nousa can you post the error message you see? Some AMS packages also use a command named `\twoheadleftarrow` so you might see an `command already defined` error. Is that the case?

Comment: i cant compile my document at all

Comment: @Nousa can you post the .log file of your document? After you attempt compilation, it should show up in the same directory as the source file.

Comment: here's my log file [link] ( http://pastebin.com/drvyhyPd)